Burnt USB C port
I was using my Raspberry Pi 5 as usual (just a headless file server with only one USB SSD drive connected) when I lost connection a few times. When I checked the status light, it was turning on and off constantly. I tried unplugging it and plugging it back in, but the Pi stopped turning on altogether. I thought there might be an issue with the cable, so I tried using a different one (I grabbed an AirPods cable nearby to ensure it wasn't a cheap cable that could cause damage), but still nothing happened.
I reconnected the first cable (a 100W-rated one from Amazon), and suddenly the cable got hot. I immediately unplugged it, and everything seemed fine. I was a bit panicked so I waited for a while to make sure everything had cooled down and decided to try powering it again. This time, I connected the Pi to my PC to prevent it from receiving too much power and used the AirPods cable again. Almost immediately, I smelled burning plastic, and after disconnecting it, I noticed the port was melted on the right side.

Rest of the board seem fine.


What could be the cause of this and what would be the best way to repair it? It never overheated or had any power issues before. I had been running it perfectly fine for over a month.
